# Finder Preview not showing details of mobile provisioning profile under Mojave

Tags: ios, finder, macos-mojave, mobileprovision

After installing `Mojave` on a new Mac, I'm noticing some issues when I open up an ipa file, browse to the `embedded.mobileprovision` profile.

When I click on the `embedded.mobileprovision` file, Mojave isn't showing me any details of the provisioning profile.  I have the latest XCode installed, and can build my apps fine.

With High Sierra, all the details of the profile are presented.  The creation/expiration dates and times show, but Under Mojave, only a generic  expires statement shows.

How can I get Mojave to show me all the details?
[image: difference between finder High Sierra and Mojave mobileprovision details]

Comment: I see the same. Would love to get the preview back.

Comment: [ProvisionQL](https://github.com/ealeksandrov/ProvisionQL) might be what you want, `brew cask install provisionql` to install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Provisioning Profile preview doesn't work correctly in Dark Mode. You need to switch back to Light Mode to see the text.

Comment: Marking correct for Mojave, seems they have fixed this in Catalina